# Receiving push notifications in iOS without alert message even when app is not active

Tags: ios, geolocation, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

From Apple's Push Notification Guide:

> If the target application isn’t running when the notification arrives, the alert message, sound, or badge value is played or shown. If the application is running, iOS delivers it to the application delegate as an NSDictionary object. The dictionary contains the corresponding Cocoa property-list objects (plus NSNull).

I have implemented this in my app and everything works fine. If the app is in focus, the app gets the message directly. If not active, an alert is shown, the app launches when the user clicks the alert, and finally the app gets hold of the message.

Would it be possible, however, in the case of a message arriving when the app is not active, to get iOS to activate the app and pass the message on without showing any message or requiring any user interaction?

I would like this behavior because the push message from my server only *might* be of interest to the user, depending on her current position. The app works like this: When it starts, it registers for push and tells my server: I am at this position and would like to be notified when something interesting happens near me. At a later point the server sends a message, but since the user might have moved from the area, I would like the app to check the user's position again, and not bother the user if she now is too far from the original position.

I suppose it would be possible to have a background service that notifies the server about the current position every *n* minutes, but I fear that this will drain the battery.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't — in iOS — directly open your app when a notification is received. The user must choose himself to open it via the alert displayed by the system.

However, using the background location is not that battery-unfriendly. It depends on the location accuracy you set for your `CLLocationManager` object.

All the informations about location accuracy can be found here : [Location Awareness Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/CoreLocation/CoreLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH2-SW10)

In your case, you may want to use the **significant location changes** methods or the `kCLLocationAccuracyKilometer` accuracy for example.

Here is a good tutorial to get started : [iOS Multitasking: Background Location](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you, a very informative answer! I will check out the links and report back on my progress